# Can't display errors, 500 internal server error

Tags: php, laravel

i have executed composer update in my local computer and then upload all vendor file in live server after that website showing

```
This page isn’t working
www.saakin.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

and my .env file is

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=somekey
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://www.saakin.com/
```

please help me out (it is a sharing server)

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? It will help you to find the cause of the issue.

Comment: Laravel has its own logs in `storage/logs`, so check there first. Otherwise, you'll have to check the server logs directly

Comment: Why can't you just do composer install on live server? Manual file upload is very tedious.

Comment: don't have access thats why i have to do that

Comment: log file not generating

Comment: maybe you have server logs? anyway check permissions of `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` folders

Comment: server is AWS, both folder have 777 permissions

Comment: open `public/index.php` and on the very top `echo "hello"; exit;` =D

Comment: i think something happen with autoloader

Comment: try run `$ php artisan optimize:clear`

Answer (score 0):

i just delete the vendor folder and run composer it's fixed my all issue thanks for the help